# Symfony : Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9D\x90\xA8\xF0\x9D...'

Tags: sql, mysql

On symfony, I have a "description" field that lets me add content, but some characters or fonts, for example the text below, don't work:

This text is considered a special character, and it returns this error when I try to save it:

> An exception occurred while executing a query: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9D\x90\xA8\xF0\x9D...' for column `MyBase`.`post`.`content` at row 1

what I tried

On my PhpMyAdmin sent this query:

```
ALTER DATABASE MyBase CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE post CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

I edited my doctrine.yaml like this :

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        # ...
        charset: utf8mb4
        default_table_options:
            charset: utf8mb4
            collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

this is a screenshot of my table :

[image: my table 'post']

But the error still persists when I try to create a post with this text.

Comment: You've shared what you've _tried_, but not what you _know_. What do you know about these characters? Which answers on Stack Overflow didn't help you? Etc. Anyway, I took your characters: _"don't work: "  ""_, tried them on my system, and they came out as: _"don't work: "ð¨ð®ð¯ð«ðšð¢ð­ ð¬ðžð¬ ð©ð¨ð«ð­ðž""_. Seems like my system can't cope with it either, and I also thought it could.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware
as far as I know, these characters are a variant of the typeface called "mathematical bold", I don't know more about it, it requires utf8mb4

Comment: I have tried to insert the    text in a column of my local database. Indeed, with the default `utf8`charset/collation it does not work. But I have set a `utf32` collation and then it worked !